# Simple way to swap row column access to array

Tags: c

My code is defining a matrix in an array:

```
int *matrix = (int[9]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

And the elements are accessed by row/column with `matrix[i * 3 + j]`.

I'm looking for a way to "swap" the access by row/column to column/row: `matrix[j * 3 + i]`, but in some way that `i` is row sometimes, and it is column in other occasions.

A not so elegant solution I found was:

```
int v[2] = {0, 0};
int i, j;

if (isRowCol) {
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
} else {
    i = 1;
    j = 0;
}

matrix[v[i] * 3 + v[j]];
```

The directives `#ifdef` would be a good idea, but it is only for compilation.

Comment: `int matrix = (int[9]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};` compiler is warning you .....

Comment: `int matrix = (int[9]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};` - this line does not make sense. You are assigning an `int` with an array compound literal. Perhaps you wanted `int *matrix`? Or better yet `int matrix[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`?

Comment: I've just corrected to `int *matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

`if` is very elegant. But if you do not want to use it:

```
int getVal(const int *array, const size_t i1, const size_t i2, const size_t rows, const size_t cols, const bool order)
{
    return array[order * (i2*cols + i1) + !order * (i2*rows + i1)];
}
```

or

```
int getVal(const int *array, const size_t i1, const size_t i2, const size_t rows, const size_t cols, const bool order)
{
    return array[order ? (i2*cols + i1) : (i2*rows + i1)];
}
```

or another similar depending what you want to archieve.

Comment: But if I need to access the array a million times, then `getVal()` would be called  the same amount.

Comment: @EqualBear0000 then make it inline. or convert to macro. There is no other way if the order is not known compile time. There is no other way than some form of the `if` or arithmetic expression